Prevent auto detection of phone numbers in Chrome mobile
I faced an issue with webpage on Chrome mobile: the block with text content being detected as phone number.
I was able to fix issue on Safari by adding meta tag.
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />

However debug output for Chrome mobile shows that text being wrapped with chrome_annotation tag.
how does block look like on desktop:
<h1 class="referral-code-text" id="referral_code">
    6132905676
</h1>

how does block look like on Chrome mobile:
<h1 class="referral-code-text" id="referral_code">
    <chrome_annotation data-index="0" data-data="4d5cea19-6226-4052-a243-c68d8d27b47a" data-annotation="6132905676" data-type="PHONE_NUMBER" role="link" style="border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-style: solid; background-color: transparent; border-bottom-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
    6132905676
    </chrome_annotation>
</h1>


Is there any way to prevent phone number detection on Chrome mobile?
Is there any way to prevent chrome_annotation tag being added on the go?


I'm not sure if this is related to your issue but there is currently an issue in the latest chrome for iOS (v127.0.6533.77) where chrome_annotation tags are added to svgs. This breaks the svgs.
That error is mentioned here:
You can disable chrome from adding these tags by adding the following meta tag to your html.
<meta name="chrome" content="nointentdetection" />
